# Add column to indicate if any other columns contains NA

Tags: r

I have a tibble with lot of NAs.
I wish to add a column that shows which is

- true when all column values do not contain NA and
- false if anyone of the column contains NA

```
tbl <- tibble(
  x1 = c(1, 0, NA, 0, NA),
  x2 = c(1, NA, NA, 0, 0),
  x3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
)

# add a column z that shows which is true all column values donot contain NA and false if anyone of the column contains NA.

tbl_desired <- tibble(
  x1 = c(1, 0, NA, 0, NA),
  x2 = c(1, NA, NA, 0, 0),
  x3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1),

  z = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `if_all` with `complete.cases`

```
library(dplyr)
tbl <- tbl %>%
    mutate(z = if_all(everything(), complete.cases))
```

-output

```
tbl
# A tibble: 5 × 4
     x1    x2    x3 z    
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     1     1     1 TRUE 
2     0    NA     0 FALSE
3    NA    NA     0 FALSE
4     0     0     0 TRUE 
5    NA     0     1 FALSE
```